# How should I learn NLTK?

Tags: python, nlp, artificial-intelligence, nltk

[NLTK](http://www.nltk.org/) is something I've been interested for a fair while, but I have been so far unaware of an efficient way to become (relatively) acquainted with NLTK.

I have done some preliminary research, which has resulted in my awareness of two online courses:
[statistics.com/nlp-using-nltk/](http://www.statistics.com/nlp-using-nltk/)

[statistics.com/nlp-using-nltk/](http://www.nltk.org/book/ch00.html)

and this ebook:
[nltk.org/book/ch00.html](http://www.nltk.org/book/ch00.html)

I would appreciate a reccomendation of an online tutorial or course, preferably in video format, that would be a good tool for me to use. If you have used one of the things that I linked to, please give me your impressions, if possible.

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it

Comment: Because the devs have painstakingly built MANY functions that can save you time and effort.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I **strongly** recommend working your way through the [NLTK book](http://www.nltk.org/book/), chapter by chapter. That's by far the best way to learn how to use NLTK, and it doesn't require much Python knowledge to get started.

Earlier this year, I put together a very basic introduction to NLTK that some people have found useful: [A Smattering of NLP in Python](https://github.com/charlieg/A-Smattering-of-NLP-in-Python).

I'm not aware of any good video tutorials for NLTK.